# Image converted by skimage.color rgba to rgb is saved as rgba by matplotlib imsave

Tags: python, matplotlib, rgb, rgba, scikit-image

I need to convert a PNG `H*W*4` `rgba` image to `rgb` image with shape `H*W*3`.

Which I am able to do but when I save it the image is saved again as `H*W*4` 
Here is the code snippet:

```
for idx, image in enumerate(image_names):
    #matplotlib as mpi here I use plt for plotting and mpi for read
    rgba = mpi.imread(os.path.join(read_path,image))
    #convert to rgb using skimage.color as rtl,
    rgb = rtl.rgba2rgb(rgba)
    #change path of the image to be saved
    resized_path = os.path.join(os.path.sep,Ims,p[0],image)
    print(np.shape(rgb))#shape is printed (136,136,3)
    mpi.imsave(resized_path,rgb)
```

After this when I read it again its shape is again `H*W*4` any Idea why? Is there anything with matplotlib `imsave` I guess?

Reference Image:

[image]

**EDIT**
UPDATED CODE like this:

```
for idx, image in enumerate(image_names):
    rgba = plt.imread(os.path.join(read_path,image))
    rgb = skimage.color.rgba2rgb(rgba)
    #original image name do not have ext and adding or removing 
    # does not effect
    resized_path = os.path.join(os.path.sep,basepath,image,".png")
    rgb = Image.fromarray((rgb*255).astype(np.uint8))
    rgb.save(resized_path)
```

Got Following error:

```
    ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-12-648b9979b4e9> in <module>()
      6         print(np.shape(rgb))
      7         rgb = Image.fromarray((rgb*255).astype(np.uint8))
----> 8         rgb.save(resized_path)
      9     #mpi.imsave(resized_path,rgb)

/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/PIL/Image.pyc in save(self, fp, format, **params)
   1809                 format = EXTENSION[ext]
   1810             except KeyError:
-> 1811                 raise ValueError('unknown file extension: {}'.format(ext))
   1812 
   1813         if format.upper() not in SAVE:

ValueError: unknown file extension:
```

**Solution**
Solved answer below is correct the only problem above was resized path and here goes the change:

```
resized_path = os.path.join(os.path.sep,Ims,p[0],image)
resized_path = (resized_path+".png")
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Matplotlib `pyplot.imsave` saves the image with an alpha channel (i.e. as RGBA) independend on whether or not the input array has such a channel present.

However, there is no loss of information, since all alpha values are `1`. Hence you can get your RGB image as

```
new_im = plt.imread("image.png")[:,:,:3]
# new_im.shape will be (<y>, <x>, 3)
```

If you specifically need a RGB png image you need to use a different means to save the image.

E.g. using PIL

```
from PIL import Image
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

im = np.random.rand(120,120,3)

im2 = Image.fromarray((im*255).astype(np.uint8))
im2.save("image2.png")

new_im = plt.imread("image2.png")  
print (new_im.shape)
# prints  (120L, 120L, 3L)
```

Comment: So this is just a workaround. Right? Is there any other way to save image without alpha channel?

Comment: Well, not with matplotlib. I added a solution using PIL.

Comment: How are you using `im2.save` here? I got this error: `'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'save'`. Besides that I can not get how/Why you are using `PIL.Image`?

Comment: The code is runnable by itself. If you don't change it, it should not produce an error. Apart, I'm not sure what you mean by "How are you using...". I'm using it just as it is written.

Comment: To clarify my ambiguity, I am reading image using `plt.imread` not a random array generated as in your case `im` so I just skipped `Image.fromarray` (Am I doing right?) So after that I got this error `'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'save'`

Comment: You need to replace `im = np.random.rand(120,120,3)` with `im = plt.imread(...)`. But **everything else needs to stay** the same.

Comment: Please check the update in my question. As change was longer than comment so I edited Question

Comment: That is a totally different issue. The pathname is apparently not correct. Print `resized_path` to see how it looks like.

Comment: Yes I am sorry, I was about to update that it was my mistake. Thank you it is working now. I am going to update the solution too.